# immutablejs (react/redux) , "push" into state with immutable

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, immutable.js

In my react/redux app, I am setting states in my reducers using something like this :

```
 state.set('search', myResults);
```

the state is an immutablejs `Map()`. The format of the object when toJS() is run on it (no longer an immutable object) is like so :

```
 {
    results: { ..all results in here }
 }
```

So you'd have `state.search.results`.

and this works great, however I have a scenario where I need to "push" into the search part of this map. I was thinking merge would take care of this however it does not seem to work as I assumed it would. I have tried :

```
  state.mergeIn('search', singleResult);
```

as well as

```
 state.merge({ 'search': singleResult });
```

neither seem to be working. The intended result is to have that single result pushed into the state `Map()` (and not overriding it like with `.set`). So the desired result would end up looking like this :

```
 {
    results: { singleResult pushed or merged into here with other results }
 }
```

I am unsure how to do this with immutablejs, any advice would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to use update for this. Merging does not concat arrays together in the key.

`state.update('search', search => search.concat(singleResult));`

Also be aware that if search contains a normal JS array - then the array itself is still an mutable data structure. Immutable.JS doesn't do deep conversion of datatypes unless you use fromJS().

Comment: toJS also does deep conversion back to JS so if i have a structure like Map({'a': List()}) then it will convert to {a: []} (If I'm understanding your question correctly.) I'm guessing you're doing state = Map({search: [results]}) - later: state.update('myanswerabove') then in your ui or elsewhere { results: state.toJS() } which would be { results: { search: results with new singleResult } }